# jQuery code works in Firebug, but not on its own

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, firebug

I'm having quite the brainbuster of an issue right now. I am trying to change a link's hash tag at the end from "respond" to "comments" with jQuery. I have a simple script that should do this, however it does not work. The link does not change. However, Firebug shows no errors and when I run the code in Firebug's console, it works just as I intend. Why doesn't this work on its own? Does anybody have a solution, I'm at my wits edge with this one.

```
(function ($) { 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href$='respond']").each(function() { 
        $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr('href').replace("respond", "comments"));
    });
  });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

Thanks so much, I know this might be a pain to test but I'm really thankful.

Comment: Where are you placing this code in your page? And are you using any other frameworks? Does the other code execute? Have you tried minimizing it?

Comment: This works for me, something else is going on outside of the posted code: http://jsfiddle.net/akgEH/  Also, do you need the noConflict?  This gets real short if you don't.

Comment: @meder I have tried the code below the element that it is editing and also in the head. Neither have worked. Yes, other frameworks are in use but I shouldn't have issues since I'm using noConflict. Other jQuery code does execute without issue. No I haven't minimized it, would that help?

@Nick That is interesting. I have tried it on a standalone html document where all there was was a link and the code in the head and it had the same results as on my site. Yes, unfortunately I do need the noConflict, I am using Wordpress and I am making use of plugins that require other frameworks.

Comment: Can you link us to said page with issue? Or replicate it on jsfiddle. It could be some Prototype extending code from another library which messes up how jQuery's `.each` or document ready code works, or event handlers may overwrite each other.

Comment: Its on the homepage of this site: http://codezroz.com/ The comment link under the latest post section is the issue.

Comment: `    console.log( jQuery("a[href$='respond']").length )` gives me 0 for the homepage, which you linked to. are you sure the issue is on the homepage

Comment: Yep, its the comment number link in the latest post section. And when I run that, I receive a value of 1.

Comment: @Ben - I see your link, but where is your script? I can't find your code anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `$(document).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.

```
(function ($) {
//---------------v
    $(document).load(function() {    
        $("a[href$='respond']").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr('href').replace("respond", "comments"));
        });  
    });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

Comment: Sorry, I put that there to see if it would make any difference and never changed it back. I just did, it doesn't help.

Comment: @Ben - You have lots of other scripts. Not sure what they all do, but it concerns me that your script is in the middle of the page, embedded in a `div`. Perhaps another script is manipulating that element and killing your code. Could you move your script to the `head` or the bottom of the page and try that?

Comment: @patrick - I have tried that before, but I suppose there is no harm in trying it again. But as I said before, I tried this on a simple page that had nothing but the link and the code in the head and it produced the same results.

Comment: @Ben - Any chance that link is being generated dynamically via some other javascript? If so, maybe it isn't on the page yet when your script runs.

Comment: @patrick - Its being generated by PHP, but that should be served before the page loads, am I correct? I have also tried applying a delay, just in case something like this was causing it, however it didn't help.

Comment: @Ben - Yeah, shouldn't matter if it is via PHP. Thought maybe some other javascript did it, but if you used a `setTimeout()`, then that's probably not the case. Just for kicks, try using the `contains` selector instead of the `ends with`: `a[href*='respond']`. Your code works fine on a test page. There's something else going on. I'll be back in about an hour.

Comment: @patrick - Take a look at this. http://codezroz.com/test.html This is the test page I referred to. Its just the code and an identical link, yet it does the same thing. Which is why I am led to believe it is an error in the code, yet I can find none.

Comment: @Ben - ...one more thing. Does *any* jQuery work for you? Try this in your `ready()` method: `alert($().jquery);` Should alert the version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: @patrick - Thanks man, I appreciate all the help. The contains selector didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Ben - I literally cut and pasted the code from your test page, as well as the `<a>` element. Works fine for me. I'll be back in a bit.

Comment: @Ben - The problem with your test page is that the opening javascript tag is misspelled `javscript`. Be back.

Comment: @patrick - Sure, take your time. Although I may have just found something. It seems none of that code is executing. When I paste the alert code into the ready() method and reload the page no alert box is shown. But I do have other jQuery code running on the page that works just fine. At least this narrows it down a bit.

Comment: @patrick The misspelling of javascript was the whole problem. Thanks so much for your help patrick. I'm sorry that the issue was just a typo. Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @Ben - Seemed like it was spelled correctly on the main page, though. Well anyway, not a problem. :o) Glad things are working for you now.

Answer (score 5):

Your code should be working fine, but your script tag is malformed. You have `text/javscript` instead of `text/javascript`. Also, you can optimize your code a little:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("a[href$='respond']").attr("href", function(index, attr){
      return attr.replace("respond", "comments");
    });
  }).noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, don't I feel dumb now...and really embarrassed. Thanks Doug. After struggling with this for 8 hours...it was because I typo'd javascript. Thanks for the help, and for the optimized code!

Comment: Not answer-crapping but shouldn't you select the person who's been helping you for the last hour?

Comment: Happy to help! I'll tell you a secret: @Jonathan Sampson (Moderator here on SO) shot me a bit of code he was troubleshooting a few months ago, and he couldn't find the error. He had `<script type="text/css">` haha. So you aren't alone :) Good luck on your site!

Comment: @meder - Shouldn't I actually mark the person who found the answer? And I apologized to patrick and am sincerely sorry for my mistake and am 100% grateful for his help.

Comment: @Ben ` The problem with your test page is that the opening javascript tag is misspelled javscript. Be back. – patrick 13 mins ago` whereas this was answered 10 mins ago.

Comment: @meder - My goodness, I never saw that. Sorry Doug but I had to switch the answer. I'm sure you understand. Thanks meder for pointing that out, I don't want to hurt anyone's feelings.

@Doug - I don't believe you ripped off the answer and am very grateful for the rewritten code.

Comment: @Doug - I don't think you ripped off his answer, I think both of you solved it independently. It's just I'm pointing out that he found it before yours, and even though you found it faster than he did, that doesn't take away from his whole time helping debug. Truthfully both of you should be selected.

Comment: @Ben no worries, I don't need the rep points, just happy you got it figured out!

Comment: Well, sorry for the trouble then.

Comment: @Doug - Thanks for understand Doug. I really appreciate it!

@meder - Thanks for trying to help patrick out. He deserved it.

Comment: @meder You of course make a totally valid point. Sorry for getting upset and railing on you :( I deleted most of my comments, so I look like less of a jerk :)

Comment: @Doug - +1 Looks like there was a bit of a storm here while I was gone. ;o) Honestly, I'd have been happy to have you get the credit just to see this one figured out when I returned. It was starting to driving me a bit crazy. :o)

Comment: @meder - Thanks for your efforts. I appreciate it. :o)

Comment: @patrick Haha... Ya, I know better but I argued anyway :) Silly me. Thanks for the nice comment!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("a[href$='respond']").each(function() { 
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr('href').replace("respond", "comments"));
  });
});
```

If you pass a function to the jQuery constructor it adds it to the DOM Ready listeners and automatically passes itself as an argument.